# How to change from VB6 Modal Userforms to ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb6

I am thinking about migrating a VB6 (winform) application to the Web in ASP .NET (C#).

In the current VB6 program the screens structure works like this:

- Login screen - enter parameters - takes you to
- Schedule screen - enter parameters - takes you to
- Barcode scanning screen - scan barcode - takes you to
- Piece count screen - enter piece count - go back to barcode screen

The top most screen(useform) must be dealt with before being able to go back to another form.

What would be the best route to take to mimic this behaviour in ASP .NET?  Or would it be better to switch the screen-centric thinking to something else?

Comment: How exactly are you going to do barcode scanning from an ASP.NET page?

Comment: scanwedge - barcode reader from computer is treated as though user was on a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is what you converting from a WebSite?  My guess is no.  Winforms would more closely model this behavior not ASP.NET.

However if you want to of ASP.NET you can do the same by each page 'Redirecting' to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx), or a [MultiView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx), in order to easy control the navigation process as you describe.  Each "screen" becomes a separate wizard "step" template, only one of which is loaded and shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just rewrite it with one ASP.net page per screen. This would give you:

Login Screen -> Login.aspx
Schedule Screen -> Schedule.aspx
Barcode scanning screen -> Scan.aspx
Piece Count Screen -> pieces.aspx

On postback of the asp form it would redirect to the next page down the line. Alternately you could have multiple panels on the page that are set to visible or not depending on where the user is in the process:

asp:Panel ID="Scheduling" . . . . 
asp:Panel ID="Scanning" . . . . 
asp:Panel ID="PieceCount" . . . .

Whatever you find easiest.

Comment: The problem with this is they can freely move to those pages by typing in the URLs, or using forward/back navigation, and not fill in the prerequisite steps.

Comment: That makes sense, I just added another approach that might work out even better which would use only one page that had conditionally displayed regions for the different screens you had previously.

Using this method you could have some members and then show the appropritate panel based on the information you have. For example, if you had scheduling info but not the barcode you'd show he barcode. If you had both scheduling AND the barcode you'd show piece count.